# php returning null http response to android

Tags: php, android, httpresponse

I am calling php url from android to recevive some string value.
**My android code is as below:**

```
       private static final String   BASE_URL="http://10.10.2.26/demo";
public static HttpResponse executeUrl(String action,String[] parameters) {


    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();



        URI website = new URI(BASE_URL+"/"+action);


        System.out.println("serverurl="+website);
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();


        request.setURI(website);

        System.out.println("5");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);


        System.out.println("no error in execute URL");
        return response;
    } catch (Exception e) {         

        System.out.println("In error of execute URL"+e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } 
    return null;
}
```

**Following is my php code:**

```
<?php

echo "kunal";
?>
```

after execution i receive null to android.

Comment: Please post your PHP code

Comment: i added the code but it is not being displayed.                      my code is <?php

echo "kunal";
?>

Comment: Btw your IP is a local address.

Comment: yes my ip is local addderess of my machine

Comment: your code seems to be ok, might be you are making mistake in getting data, have look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569689/android-http-response-handling

Comment: i am getting exception null here                                                              my response is returned null                                                                                                                                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
  return response;

Comment: is my php code right ?

Comment: kindly help me the above code was running fine and i had gone further with my coding but again i am facing same problem response null from server  HttpResponse response = client.execute(request); return response null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code for retrieving  values from php. It is working fine.

```
private void get_valueFromPhp(String php) {
    String responseString = null;

    try{    
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String url ="your url"; 
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
        out.close();
        responseString = out.toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),responseString,1000).show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to open your url:

```
http://10.10.2.26/demo
```

With your phone browser. Probably you are not in the same network.

Comment: i am currently running on my laptop on emulator.  and the url is executing on my phone browser correctly